# AndEngine strange error is crashing game

Tags: java, android, andengine, sprite

So, the idea here is collect the three logs, easy quest.
But I can only get the logs in a specific order, or touching the log crashes the app. Why?
If I grab them in order it works, but if i touch log 2 or 3 first, it crashes.
Is there a better way to do this?

```
public void initQuestTwo() {


        createHUD();


    logSprite = new Sprite(300, 300, AssetLoaderUtil.logTextureRegion,
            mContext.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {

        @Override
        protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

            if (mPlayerSprite.collidesWith(this)) {


                    numberOfLogs++;


                    mContext.toastOnUIThread("Got log " + numberOfLogs + "/3",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);


                    SceneManager.mWorldScene.detachChild(logSprite);



                }
            }




    };





    log2Sprite = new Sprite(100, 400, AssetLoaderUtil.logTextureRegion,
            mContext.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {

        @Override
        protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

            if (mPlayerSprite.collidesWith(this)) {


                numberOfLogs++;


                mContext.toastOnUIThread("Got log " + numberOfLogs + "/3",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);


                SceneManager.mWorldScene.detachChild(log2Sprite);


            }
        }

    };


    log3Sprite = new Sprite(250, 30, AssetLoaderUtil.logTextureRegion,
            mContext.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {

        @Override
        protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

            if (mPlayerSprite.collidesWith(this)) {


                numberOfLogs++;


                mContext.toastOnUIThread("Got log " + numberOfLogs + "/3",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);


                SceneManager.mWorldScene.detachChild(log3Sprite);



            }
        }

    };


    logSprite.setZIndex(10);
    this.attachChild(logSprite);

    log2Sprite.setZIndex(10);
    this.attachChild(log2Sprite);

    log3Sprite.setZIndex(10);
    this.attachChild(log3Sprite);

}
```

```
/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
10-16 20:02:43.402: D/libEGL(5264): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
10-16 20:02:43.473: I/ActivityManager(478): Displayed WorldScene.test.test/.WorldActivity: +2s620ms (total +16s686ms)
10-16 20:02:43.481: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(831): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
10-16 20:02:43.543: D/AndEngine(5264): VERSION: OpenGL ES 2.0 build 1.9.RC2@2139099
10-16 20:02:43.543: D/AndEngine(5264): RENDERER: PowerVR SGX 540
10-16 20:02:43.543: D/AndEngine(5264): EGLCONFIG: EGLConfig(Red=5, Green=6, Blue=5, Alpha=0, Depth=0, Stencil=0)
10-16 20:02:43.543: D/AndEngine(5264): EXTENSIONS: GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_OES_fragment_precision_high GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_required_internalformat GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_OES_egl_sync GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod GL_IMG_shader_binary GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc GL_IMG_texture_npot GL_IMG_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_IMG_read_format GL_IMG_program_binary GL_IMG_uniform_buffer_object GL_IMG_multisampled_render_to_texture
10-16 20:02:43.543: D/AndEngine(5264): MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS: 8
10-16 20:02:43.543: D/AndEngine(5264): MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS: 128
10-16 20:02:43.543: D/AndEngine(5264): MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS: 64
10-16 20:02:43.543: D/AndEngine(5264): MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS: 8
10-16 20:02:43.543: D/AndEngine(5264): MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 2048
10-16 20:02:43.543: D/AndEngine(5264): WorldActivity.onSurfaceCreated @(Thread: 'GLThread 1233')
10-16 20:02:43.543: D/AndEngine(5264): WorldActivity.onCreateGame @(Thread: 'GLThread 1233')
10-16 20:02:43.551: D/AndEngine(5264): WorldActivity.onCreateResources @(Thread: 'GLThread 1233')
10-16 20:02:43.621: D/AndEngine(5264): WorldActivity.onCreateScene @(Thread: 'GLThread 1233')
10-16 20:02:43.738: D/AndEngine(5264): WorldActivity.onPopulateScene @(Thread: 'GLThread 1233')
10-16 20:02:43.738: D/AndEngine(5264): WorldActivity.onGameCreated @(Thread: 'GLThread 1233')
10-16 20:02:43.738: D/AndEngine(5264): WorldActivity.onSurfaceChanged(Width=810,  Height=540) @(Thread: 'GLThread 1233')
10-16 20:02:43.738: D/AndEngine(5264): WorldActivity.onResumeGame @(Thread: 'main')
10-16 20:02:43.910: D/dalvikvm(5264): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 713K, 10% free 8349K/9187K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
10-16 20:02:43.910: I/dalvikvm-heap(5264): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.805MB for 1659856-byte allocation
10-16 20:02:43.965: D/dalvikvm(5264): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 13K, 9% free 9956K/10851K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
10-16 20:02:43.973: D/dalvikvm(5264): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 9% free 9956K/10851K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
10-16 20:02:43.981: I/dalvikvm-heap(5264): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.958MB for 3319696-byte allocation
10-16 20:02:44.012: D/dalvikvm(5264): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 7% free 13198K/14115K, paused 19ms+2ms, total 34ms
10-16 20:02:44.035: D/dalvikvm(5264): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 7% free 13198K/14115K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
10-16 20:02:44.043: I/dalvikvm-heap(5264): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.541MB for 1659856-byte allocation
10-16 20:02:44.309: D/wifi(478): doString: SIGNAL_POLL
10-16 20:02:44.981: D/dalvikvm(5264): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 7% free 14819K/15779K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
10-16 20:02:45.012: D/dalvikvm(5264): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
10-16 20:02:45.035: D/dalvikvm(5264): GC_EXPLICIT freed 6493K, 48% free 8326K/15779K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 25ms
10-16 20:02:45.043: D/dalvikvm(5264): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
10-16 20:02:45.067: D/dalvikvm(5264): GC_EXPLICIT freed 18K, 48% free 8327K/15779K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 25ms
10-16 20:02:45.098: D/dalvikvm(5264): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
10-16 20:02:45.121: D/dalvikvm(5264): GC_EXPLICIT freed 39K, 48% free 8327K/15779K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 24ms
10-16 20:02:45.137: D/GameIntro(5264): Current Timeline Item: 0 max: 3
10-16 20:02:45.293: D/dalvikvm(478): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
10-16 20:02:45.504: D/dalvikvm(478): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3473K, 28% free 22460K/30819K, paused 5ms+18ms, total 208ms
10-16 20:02:45.660: D/GameIntro(5264): Current Timeline Item: 1 max: 3
10-16 20:02:47.317: D/wifi(478): doString: SIGNAL_POLL
10-16 20:02:47.676: D/GameIntro(5264): Current Timeline Item: 2 max: 3
10-16 20:02:48.699: D/GameIntro(5264): Size: 3 Finished!
10-16 20:02:48.699: D/GameIntro(5264): Unregistered!
10-16 20:02:48.746: D/AndEngine(5264): FPS: 43.16 (MIN: 17 ms | MAX: 1396 ms)
10-16 20:02:48.879: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 0 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:02:48.879: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 0 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:02:49.129: D/dalvikvm(5264): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
10-16 20:02:49.152: D/dalvikvm(5264): GC_EXPLICIT freed 297K, 47% free 8392K/15779K, paused 1ms+3ms, total 28ms
10-16 20:02:49.231: D/dalvikvm(5264): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
10-16 20:02:49.277: D/dalvikvm(5264): GC_EXPLICIT freed 780K, 47% free 8439K/15779K, paused 12ms+13ms, total 43ms
10-16 20:02:49.918: D/Tethering(478): interfaceLinkStateChanged wlan0, true
10-16 20:02:49.918: D/Tethering(478): interfaceStatusChanged wlan0, true
10-16 20:02:49.918: D/wifi(478): doBoolean: AP_SCAN 1
10-16 20:02:49.926: D/wifi(478): doString: SCAN_RESULTS
10-16 20:02:49.934: D/LSAPP_LSDet(3278): hasPoi:...no POIs !
10-16 20:02:49.934: D/LSAPP_Beacon(3278): notifyAllCallers : notify caller POI=null caller:Handler (com.motorola.contextual.virtualsensor.locationsensor.LocationDetection$MessageHandler) {41796eb8}
10-16 20:02:49.934: E/LSApp_App(3278): Sending Message to Handler (com.motorola.contextual.virtualsensor.locationsensor.LocationDetection$MessageHandler) {41796eb8}: msg :1010002
10-16 20:02:49.934: D/LSAPP_LSDet(3278): matchBeacons: Beacon no match any poi...:
10-16 20:02:49.934: D/LSAPP_LSDet(3278): startDetection: celltower changed : do nothing because not in a poi and cells are not POI cells ::{"NetTyp":"CDMA","BaseStnLat":"2147483647","NetOp":"","BaseStnId":"0","BaseStnLng":"2147483647","CntryISO":"","NetId":"0","SysId":"0"}
10-16 20:02:49.934: D/LSAPP_TimerTask(3278): stopPeriodicalUpdate : network provider:false wifiscan: true
10-16 20:02:50.317: D/wifi(478): doString: SIGNAL_POLL
10-16 20:02:52.606: W/AndEngine(5264): No ITextureRegion supplied for State.PRESSED.
10-16 20:02:52.606: W/AndEngine(5264): No ITextureRegion supplied for State.DISABLED.
10-16 20:02:52.613: W/AndEngine(5264): No ITextureRegion supplied for State.PRESSED.
10-16 20:02:52.613: W/AndEngine(5264): No ITextureRegion supplied for State.DISABLED.
10-16 20:02:52.629: W/AndEngine(5264): No ITextureRegion supplied for State.PRESSED.
10-16 20:02:52.629: W/AndEngine(5264): No ITextureRegion supplied for State.DISABLED.
10-16 20:02:52.645: W/AndEngine(5264): No ITextureRegion supplied for State.PRESSED.
10-16 20:02:52.645: W/AndEngine(5264): No ITextureRegion supplied for State.DISABLED.
10-16 20:02:52.684: D/dalvikvm(5264): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
10-16 20:02:52.707: D/dalvikvm(5264): GC_EXPLICIT freed 165K, 46% free 8525K/15779K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 25ms
10-16 20:02:52.754: D/dalvikvm(5264): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
10-16 20:02:52.785: D/dalvikvm(5264): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5K, 46% free 8527K/15779K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 27ms
10-16 20:02:52.863: V/AndEngine(5264):     org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 1 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:02:52.863: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 1 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:02:52.879: D/dalvikvm(5264): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
10-16 20:02:52.895: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 2 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:02:52.895: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 2 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:02:52.910: D/dalvikvm(5264): GC_EXPLICIT freed 16K, 46% free 8529K/15779K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 30ms
10-16 20:02:53.324: D/wifi(478): doString: SIGNAL_POLL
10-16 20:02:53.801: D/AndEngine(5264): FPS: 35.01 (MIN: 17 ms | MAX: 241 ms)
10-16 20:02:54.176: W/AndEngine(5264):  changed its State to PRESSED, which doesn't have a ITextureRegion supplied. Applying default ITextureRegion.
10-16 20:02:55.301: I/SBar.NetworkController(598): updateTelephonySignalStrength:  No service
10-16 20:02:55.504: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 3 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:02:55.504: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 3 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:02:55.543: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 4 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:02:55.543: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 4 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:02:55.574: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 5 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:02:55.574: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 5 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:02:55.598: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 6 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:02:55.598: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 6 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:02:56.324: D/wifi(478): doString: SIGNAL_POLL
10-16 20:02:58.824: D/AndEngine(5264): FPS: 13.98 (MIN: 44 ms | MAX: 424 ms)
10-16 20:02:59.332: D/wifi(478): doString: SIGNAL_POLL
10-16 20:02:59.988: V/AlarmManager(478): sending alarm Alarm{41a5c078 type 3 android}
10-16 20:03:02.332: D/wifi(478): doString: SIGNAL_POLL
10-16 20:03:03.777: D/AndEngine(5264): FPS: 13.11 (MIN: 44 ms | MAX: 409 ms)
10-16 20:03:04.090: W/AndEngine(5264): No ITextureRegion supplied for State.PRESSED.
10-16 20:03:04.098: W/AndEngine(5264): No ITextureRegion supplied for State.DISABLED.
10-16 20:03:04.098: W/AndEngine(5264): No ITextureRegion supplied for State.PRESSED.
10-16 20:03:04.098: W/AndEngine(5264): No ITextureRegion supplied for State.DISABLED.
10-16 20:03:04.106: W/AndEngine(5264): No ITextureRegion supplied for State.PRESSED.
10-16 20:03:04.106: W/AndEngine(5264): No ITextureRegion supplied for State.DISABLED.
10-16 20:03:04.121: W/AndEngine(5264): No ITextureRegion supplied for State.PRESSED.
10-16 20:03:04.121: W/AndEngine(5264): No ITextureRegion supplied for State.DISABLED.
10-16 20:03:05.332: D/wifi(478): doString: SIGNAL_POLL
10-16 20:03:08.340: D/wifi(478): doString: SIGNAL_POLL
10-16 20:03:08.770: D/AndEngine(5264): FPS: 10.74 (MIN: 46 ms | MAX: 434 ms)
10-16 20:03:09.996: D/wifi(478): doBoolean: AP_SCAN 1
10-16 20:03:09.996: D/wifi(478): doString: SCAN_RESULTS
10-16 20:03:09.996: D/Tethering(478): interfaceLinkStateChanged wlan0, true
10-16 20:03:10.004: D/Tethering(478): interfaceStatusChanged wlan0, true
10-16 20:03:10.012: D/LSAPP_LSDet(3278): hasPoi:...no POIs !
10-16 20:03:10.012: D/LSAPP_Beacon(3278): notifyAllCallers : notify caller POI=null caller:Handler (com.motorola.contextual.virtualsensor.locationsensor.LocationDetection$MessageHandler) {41796eb8}
10-16 20:03:10.012: E/LSApp_App(3278): Sending Message to Handler (com.motorola.contextual.virtualsensor.locationsensor.LocationDetection$MessageHandler) {41796eb8}: msg :1010002
10-16 20:03:10.020: D/LSAPP_LSDet(3278): matchBeacons: Beacon no match any poi...:
10-16 20:03:10.020: D/LSAPP_LSDet(3278): startDetection: celltower changed : do nothing because not in a poi and cells are not POI cells ::{"NetTyp":"CDMA","BaseStnLat":"2147483647","NetOp":"","BaseStnId":"0","BaseStnLng":"2147483647","CntryISO":"","NetId":"0","SysId":"0"}
10-16 20:03:10.020: D/LSAPP_TimerTask(3278): stopPeriodicalUpdate : network provider:false wifiscan: true
10-16 20:03:11.348: D/wifi(478): doString: SIGNAL_POLL
10-16 20:03:11.535: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 7 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:11.535: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 7 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:11.574: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 8 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:11.574: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 8 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:11.606: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 9 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:11.606: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 9 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:11.723: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 10 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:11.723: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 10 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:11.746: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 11 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:11.746: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 11 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:11.777: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 12 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:11.777: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 12 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:12.277: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 13 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:12.277: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 13 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:12.309: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 14 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:12.309: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 14 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:12.340: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 15 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:12.340: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 15 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:12.371: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 16 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.    
10-16 20:03:12.371: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 16 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:12.402: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 17 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:12.402: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 17 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:12.442: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 18 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:12.442: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 18 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:12.465: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 19 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:12.465: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 19 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:12.488: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 20 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:12.488: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 20 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:12.871: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 21 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:12.871: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 21 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:12.910: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 22 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:12.910: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 22 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:12.957: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 23 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:12.957: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 23 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.    
10-16 20:03:12.988: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 24 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:12.988: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 24 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:13.020: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 25 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:13.020: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 25 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:13.043: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 26 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:13.043: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 26 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:13.285: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 27 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:13.285: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 27 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:13.324: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 28 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:13.324: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 28 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:13.356: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 29 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:13.356: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 29 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:13.395: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 30 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:13.395: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 30 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:13.410: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 31 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:13.410: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 31 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:13.442: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 32 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:13.442: V/AndEngine(5264): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 32 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
10-16 20:03:14.356: D/wifi(478): doString: SIGNAL_POLL
10-16 20:03:15.332: I/SBar.NetworkController(598): updateTelephonySignalStrength:  No service
10-16 20:03:16.684: W/dalvikvm(5264): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d072a0)
10-16 20:03:16.699: E/AndroidRuntime(5264): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
10-16 20:03:16.699: E/AndroidRuntime(5264): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 13, size is 13
10-16 20:03:16.699: E/AndroidRuntime(5264):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
10-16 20:03:16.699: E/AndroidRuntime(5264):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
10-16 20:03:16.699: E/AndroidRuntime(5264):     at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedUpdate(Entity.java:1402)
10-16 20:03:16.699: E/AndroidRuntime(5264):     at org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onManagedUpdate(Scene.java:284)
10-16 20:03:16.699: E/AndroidRuntime(5264):     at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onUpdate(Entity.java:1167)
10-16 20:03:16.699: E/AndroidRuntime(5264):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdateScene(Engine.java:604)
10-16 20:03:16.699: E/AndroidRuntime(5264):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdate(Engine.java:599)
10-16 20:03:16.699: E/AndroidRuntime(5264):     at org.andengine.engine.LimitedFPSEngine.onUpdate(LimitedFPSEngine.java:51)
10-16 20:03:16.699: E/AndroidRuntime(5264):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:561)
10-16 20:03:16.699: E/AndroidRuntime(5264):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:833)
10-16 20:03:16.715: W/ActivityManager(478):   Force finishing activity WorldScene.test.test/.WorldActivity
10-16 20:03:16.754: D/AndEngine(5264): WorldActivity.onPause @(Thread: 'main')
10-16 20:03:16.770: W/ApplicationContext(478): Unable to create files directory files
10-16 20:03:17.254: W/ActivityManager(478): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4262cfc0 WorldScene.test.test/.WorldActivity}
10-16 20:03:17.277: I/InputManager-JNI(478): Setting pointerVelocityControlParameters.acceleration 3.000000 2.
10-16 20:03:17.277: I/InputReader(478): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
10-16 20:03:17.277: I/InputReader(478): Device reconfigured: id=2, name='atmxt-i2c', surface size is now 540x960, mode is 1
10-16 20:03:17.301: D/ExtDispService(786): onRotationChanged - rotation = 0
10-16 20:03:17.301: D/ExtDispService(786): onRotationChanged! - PORTRAIT!!!
10-16 20:03:17.301: D/IExtDispIpcCB(214): BnExtDispIpcCB NOTIFYCB: type:101; ext1:1; ext2:0;
10-16 20:03:17.309: D/HWC_HDMI_MOT(214): IpcCB notifyCallback: type:101; ext1:1; ext2:0;
10-16 20:03:17.309: D/HWC_HDMI_MOT(214): IpcCB notifyCallback: UI Orientation state change - rotation = 0
10-16 20:03:17.309: D/ti_hwc(214): hdmi_callback: UI Rotation = 0
10-16 20:03:17.309: I/ActivityManager(478): Config changed: {1.0 311mcc480mnc en_US sw360dp w360dp h614dp nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.99}
10-16 20:03:17.356: I/PortalService(775): onConfigurationChanged
10-16 20:03:17.356: D/wifi(478): doString: SIGNAL_POLL
10-16 20:03:17.356: I/SystemUIService(598): onConfigurationChanged reached.
10-16 20:03:17.356: I/SystemUIService(598): isLayoutXLarge = false
10-16 20:03:17.395: W/ResourceType(831): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
10-16 20:03:17.410: D/EvbridgeService(775): handleIntent() android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED handled by com.android.portal.EvbridgeService@4151ec60
10-16 20:03:17.426: D/SizeAdaptiveLayout(598): com.android.internal.widget.SizeAdaptiveLayout@417a3778child view android.widget.FrameLayout@416948a8 measured out of bounds at 95px clamped to 96px
10-16 20:03:17.426: D/SizeAdaptiveLayout(598): com.android.internal.widget.SizeAdaptiveLayout@41927cc0child view android.widget.FrameLayout@4192dd68 measured out of bounds at 95px clamped to 96px
10-16 20:03:17.465: D/Launcher.Model(831): onReceive intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 }
10-16 20:03:17.473: I/SBar.NetworkController(598): onReceive: Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED Received
10-16 20:03:17.473: I/SBar.NetworkController(598): updateTelephonySignalStrength:  No service
10-16 20:03:17.668: I/ActivityManager(478): No longer want android.process.media (pid 19123): hidden #21
10-16 20:03:19.535: D/dalvikvm(478): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
10-16 20:03:19.746: D/dalvikvm(478): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2342K, 33% free 20749K/30819K, paused 17ms+11ms, total 212ms
10-16 20:03:20.363: D/wifi(478): doString: SIGNAL_POLL
10-16 20:03:23.363: D/wifi(478): doString: SIGNAL_POLL
10-16 20:03:26.371: D/wifi(478): doString: SIGNAL_POLL
10-16 20:03:27.676: W/ActivityManager(478): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{4262cfc0 WorldScene.test.test/.WorldActivity}
```

Note: That took a very long time to indent every line..

Comment: Have you posted the entire stack trace from your Logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you are detaching a child, it needs to be run on the update thread.

```
mContext.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        SceneManager.mWorldScene.detachChild(logSprite);
    }

});
```

Comment: But it says, I cannot make a static reference to the non-static method from the type BaseGameActivity

Comment: See my update. I was just using a generic example, but it looks like you have a reference to your activity that you can use.

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much! It seems I need to add that in quite a few places. Why did it not crash other sprites?

Comment: It's a race condition, so it may or may not crash each time. Basically, if you do not run on the update thread you are modifying the ArrayList of Sprites to be rendered at the same time the sprites may be in the process of getting updated. If the update thread thinks the ArrayList is a certain size and you remove one mid-iteration it will crash.